# How to prevent app from being cached in android

Tags: android, caching, xamarin, xamarin.android

After some research I found that Android likes to cache some parts of an app while installing to improve the performance while runtime.

Is there a way to prevent Android from caching things from my app?

I am sharing my app via my website and users install and update the app manually. As soon as I update my app some Activities and Code-parts seems to be cached on their devices.

Comment: What do you mean "some Activities and Code-parts seems to be cached" ?

Comment: If a colleague of mine installs my app he gets some Layouts and Activities which have been replaced in the version he has installed. So the App seems to use old data for display.

Comment: You could clear the cache everytime when you update it?

Comment: @JordyDieltjens yes but I am just providing a new apk-File to download and isntall. So there not really a way to execute code while this is going on

Comment: Activities and layouts? What are you doing? Honestly I have never see such a problem.....Did you change anything in the Android device settings (for example inside the debugger options of the phone)? It is true Android stores in cache some application information (such as http requests and so on....) but I never heard of anything like "caching" Activities. It is true that since Android 5.0, Android uses ART, which do a "precompilation" of the apps when instaling in order to improve performance, but it doesn't store Activities or layouts. Check again about the preferences of the device.

Comment: @zapotec could you please read the comments above?

Comment: I was reading, but it is not very clear to me if the proble is the data which is cache (by the data, I mean the respository data ex database, http request, etc...) or if it is the layout itself and the Activity code......If it is the database, it is ok, it is normal, Android has a way to automatically detect the database version and to do an upgrade (in fact, yu can then trigger some updates and so on). If the problem is your layout........you are doing something wrong on your device

Comment: @zapotec I wrote above that you should re-read the comments because the question is not about MY phone. It is about the phone of one of my COLLEAGUES. NOT MINE. HIS PHONE...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could delete your cache everytime before you update or before you close you application.
Code to clear the cache:

```
 public static void trimCache(Context context) {
      try {
         File dir = context.getCacheDir();
         if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            deleteDir(dir);
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         // TODO: handle exception
      }
   }

   public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
      if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
         String[] children = dir.list();
         for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
               return false;
            }
         }
      }

      // The directory is now empty so delete it
      return dir.delete();
   }
```

Call Trimcache when you want to clear the cache (before you update perhaps? or override the `onStop()` method, to clear the cache when the application is going to close.

Comment: I am trying this approach and hopefully its what I need for my app. Thanks

Comment: Hey Jordy, I have not been able to test it yet. There were no more distributions since then. But I will catch up to you as I have some results.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see you should also have a cache problem when you're NOT updating your app.

If you want to force a server fetch when you upgrade your app you could store a boolean in Shared Preferences, using a key associated with the app version. So when you install version 1 you fetch and make `putsBoolean(version, true)` where version == "1". When version 2 is installed you'll find a false, which will trigger a fetch, followed by setting `putsBoolean(version, true)` - but in this case version == "2".

If you are reusing information that have a different meaning when you update, the solution is storing the information in a different part of the cache, so it's not sent to an activity that is not prepared to display it.

Otherwise the solution by @jordy-dieltjens seems a good one.